# Differential Equation by Minimization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, inner-products, euler-lagrange-equation, constants

Suppose we want to solve $u + xu' = 0$, which has the general solution $u = \frac{C}{x}$, by minimizing the length squared of $u + xu'$.  This should work due to the positive definite condition of inner products.

The inner product $\int_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x)\ dx$ appears as good as any.  This gives us $\int_{-1}^{1} u^2 + 2xuu' + x^2(u')^2\ dx$.  According to the Euler-Lagrange Equation, we want to solve $\frac{\partial (u^2 + 2xuu' + x^2(u')^2)}{\partial u} - \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial (u^2 + 2xuu' + x^2(u')^2)}{\partial u'}) = 0$.  Simplifying, $2u + 2xu' - \frac{d}{dx}(2xu + 2x^2u') = 0$, thus $x^2u'' + 2xu' = 0$.  Wolfram solves this second order ODE as $u = \frac{C_1}{x} + C_2$.

The problem is that unless $C_2 = 0$, this doesn't satisfy the original ODE.  It doesn't even have the right number of arbitrary constants.  $C_1$ behaves as it should in a general solution, but $C_2$ demands to be fixed at a particular value.  What is wrong with my reasoning and/or calculations?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Euler-Lagrange equation is incomplete information for an extremal with the *free* end points (no constraints on $u(0)$ and $u(1)$). It must be completed with the *natural boundary conditions*. In your case, the latter becomes 
$$
\frac{d}{du'}L(x,u(x),u'(x))\Big|_{x=1}=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad u(1)+u'(1)=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad C_1+C_2-C_1=C_2=0.
$$